# How to sort image sequences (with different extensions) in python

Tags: python, sorting

I have this:

```
list = ["0001.exr", "0003.exr", "0002.dpx", "0001.dpx", "0002.exr", "0003.dpx"]

list.sort()

for line in list:
    print (line)
```

And it's returning this:

> 0001.dpx
>
> 0001.exr
>
> 0002.dpx
>
> 0002.exr
>
> 0003.dpx
>
> 0003.exr

How can I return this result? (in a nice simple way)

> 0001.dpx
>
> 0002.dpx
>
> 0003.dpx
>
> 0001.exr
>
> 0002.exr
>
> 0003.exr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a key for `.sort()` that puts what's after `"."` as more important than what is before it:

```
list.sort(key=lambda l: "".join(reversed(l.split(".")))
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you @zondo

Answer (score 2):

You sort according to name, then use the OS library to get the extension and sort according to it (as a key):

```
list.sort()
list.sort(key=lambda list_item: os.path.splitext(list_item)[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built in `sorted()` function with a custom `cmp` function called `sort`:

```
l = ["0001.exr", "0003.exr", "0002.dpx", "0001.dpx", "0002.exr", "0003.dpx"]

def sort(a, b):
    if 'dpx' in a and 'exr' in b:
        return -1
    if float(a.split('.')[0]) < float(b.split('.')[0]):
        return -1
    return 1

answer = sorted(l, cmp=sort)
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
['0001.dpx', '0002.dpx', '0003.dpx', '0001.exr', '0002.exr', '0003.exr']
```

As an aside, you shouldn't mask the built-in `list()` function by using `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ["0001.exr", "0003.exr", "0002.dpx", "0001.dpx", "0002.exr", "0003.dpx"]

lst_tuple=[]
for item in list:
  lst_tuple.append((item.split('.')[0],item.split('.')[1]))


print sorted(lst_tuple, key=lambda element: (element[1], element[0]))
```